# working with modprobe for getting wifi driver working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, modprobe

After several months of research finally my wifi driver is being detected and working fine ;)
That's good news with credits where i found solution is [here](http://mtotschn.blogspot.in/2012/09/d-link-dwa-525-a2-on-ubuntu-1204.html)

Now, i still have one issue that every time I have to follow instructions to set modprobe done ( as per the instructions given in link).

Can someone help me out on how to make it done automatically when system starts? i have ubuntu 12.04, Linux kernerl 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd add it to the end of `/etc/modules`. Here's a command that will handle that for you. Stick it in a terminal.

```
echo rt2800pci | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: sorry for my stupidity in asking this question. do i have to copy any of files to /etc/modules or just add above line to /etc/modules/

Comment: If you have the module available (which you should do if you followed that tutorial), you just need to run that. `/etc/modules` is a file not a directory anyway. You may find you need to rebuild the module when kernel updates land though.

Comment: And don't be so hard on yourself. These aren't stupid questions. It's not an obvious topic.